# Django - Auth Login using the jQuery

Tags: jquery, django

When I click the login button I want to go to the index page. Do not know whether I should write jQuery. I want to get the help of professionals.

**o views.py**  **- updated**

```
from django.contrib.auth import (
    authenticate,
    get_user_model,
    login,
    logout,

    )
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout

from .forms import LoginForm

def login_view(request):
    print(request.user.is_authenticated())
    next = request.GET.get('next')
    form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request, user)
        if next:
            return redirect(next)
        return redirect("/")
    return render(request, "accounts/form.html")
```

**o template**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="title" data-animation="fadeInDown" data-animation-delay=".8s">
        <h1>SOA</h1>
         <h5>Storage Operation Automation</h5>
    </div>
    <div id="form_1" data-animation="bounceIn">
        <div class="form-header">
            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
        </div>
                <div class="form-main">
                <form method="POST" action="{% url 'login' %}">{% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" id="un_1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required="required" name ="username">
                    <input type="password" id="pw_1" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="required" name="password">
                 </div>
                                 <button id="signIn_1" type="submit" class="btn btn-block signin">LOG IN</button>
                        </form>
         </div>
        <div class="form-footer">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-7">
                <i class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></i>
                <a href="#password_recovery" id="forgot_from_1">FORGET PASSWORD</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                <a href="#signup_window" id="signup_from_1">Register</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

**o jQuery** **- updated**

```
(function($) {

    // custom checkbox skin plugin
    $('input').iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal-orange',
    radioClass: 'iradio_minimal-orange',
    increaseArea: '20%' // optional
  });

    // sign in form 1
    $('#signIn_1').click(function (e) {  
        var username = $.trim($('#un_1').val());
        var password = $.trim($('#pw_1').val());
        if ( username == '' && password == '' ) {
            $('#form_1 .fa-user').removeClass('success').addClass('fail');
            $('#form_1').addClass('fail');          
        } else if ( username == 'username' && password == 'password'){
            $('#form_1 .fa-user').removeClass('fail').addClass('success');
            $('#form_1').removeClass('fail').removeClass('animated');
            return false;
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "index/index.html",
                data : "{ username : username, password : password }"
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#form_1 .fa-user').removeClass('fail').addClass('success');
                    $('#form_1').removeClass('fail').removeClass('animated');
                }
            return false;
        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

**o Display**

http://14.63.253.232/login/

[image]

Comment: Why are you doing this using AJAX? It would be much easier just to have a regular form which redirects you to the appropriate location after logging in.

Comment: @solarissmoke I hope the creating the login page using the ajax. Was it difficult method ?

Comment: If you just want to redirect to a page after login just add "next" in **action="{% url 'login' %}?next=_relative path here_"** . You can even use next in the url in urls.py which will always redirect the user to _next_ after login.

Comment: @KapilSachdev okay, I edited this question

Comment: @lovethesky I'm unable to understand ,do you want the user to get redirected to the /index url or something after he login ?

Comment: @KapilSachdev Yes, I want to get the login page after login

Comment: @lovethesky That's weird, we shouldn't allow an authnticated user to visit the login page again. Have you tried **?next=/login** , it just adds the get request to the given parameter after submit. You can also use **?next={{request.path}}** to get to the page from where user logins.

Comment: @KapilSachdev 
Thank you. Let's try again . Have a nice day